# Difference between medical device status: CE mark versus FDA approval

Tags: regulations

Can anyone tell me what the exact difference is between a medical device getting a [**CE mark**](http://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/index_en.htm) versus **[FDA approval](http://www.fda.gov/MedicalDevices/ProductsandMedicalProcedures/DeviceApprovalsandClearances/)**?

As far as I know, a CE mark only means that a medical device conforms to the European Standard of electronic engineering and that its use is considered reasonably safe.

However, **it does not tell you anything about the functionality of the device**, or does it? That is unlike an FDA approval in the USA where, as far as I understand, an important requirement is that it is deemed safe, but also has been proven to be **functional and effective** as well.

Am I correct to say that a CE mark for medical devices is about *safety* and FDA approval is about *safety + effectiveness*?

I'm having a hard time getting to the bottom of this. Many sites are quite intransparent. If possible, please mention your sources in the answer so I can read further on the topic.

Comment: Yes, CE markings do not say anything about effectiveness. For radio devices there is some certification that the device functions in the presence of interference.

Comment: For medical devices, assume there is a separate set of EN regulations to comply with, over and above CE, that will probably be broadly in line with the FDA requirements. "Reasonably safe" and "safe enough to be approved for medical use" are very different things. I'm not an expert on the specifics, hopefully someone else here is.

Comment: The CE mark actually does not mean that much, it means that the product uses materials approved by the EU and is manufactured in a EU approved way. The marking says nothing about the quality or working of the product as far as I know.

Comment: Exactly what it means varies between product categories. Devices are supposed to have a "statement of conformity" listing which standards they are claimed to conform to which you can then look up on http://www.etsi.org/ , but there's a huge mountain of documentation there.

Answer (score 2):

Medical Device CE Guidances are available at http://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/medical-devices/guidance/index_en.htm  and the relevant council directive is at http://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/medical-devices/guidance/index_en.htm

Regs differ by class of device, but the [Class 1 guidance](http://file:///C:/Users/sseidman/Downloads/notes-for-manufacturers-class1-09_en.pdf) states

> Devices must be designed and manufactured in such a way that, when used under normal conditions of use and for the purposes intended by
>   the manufacturer, they will not compromise the clinical condition or
>   the safety of patients or the safety and health of users or other
>   persons, provided that any risks which may be associated with their
>   use constitute acceptable risks when weighed against the benefits to
>   the patient and are compatible with a high level of protection of
>   health and safety.

In general, my unconfirmed understanding is that CE is safety and FDA is safety and efficacy (I'm sure about the FDA, not the CE), and that its usually simpler to get a device through CE.  When a lack of efficacy puts the safety and health of a user at risk, I *believe* this falls under CE purview, but for the small stuff, efficacy is caveat emptor.

I may have CE wrong, but I think I've linked you to the resources to pore through that can set you right.  Good luck!

IIRC, one case where FDA regs/enforcements saved the US consumer's butt was leaky breast implants.  A search for this issue didn't bring me to the heart of that issue, but http://www.consultingroom.com/Blog/269/breast-implants:-what-is-the-difference-between-the-ce-mark-&-fda-approval? (a fine implant manufacturer, so far as I know), suggests that medium class devices require no clinical data in the CE, but do for the FDA.  Actually, I know class 2 devices in the US might or might not need clinical data to support a 510K application for substantial equivalence.